# the left element of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm using a 2d array to compare elements with each other. I know that if I want to see if an element is the lowest element in a column, i do:

```
 if(array[i][j]==array[array.length-1][j])
```

What I was wondering is how I find if the element is the left-most or the right-most element in the array?

Comment: assuming the array runs left to right, 0 to max, leftmost: `if( j==0 )` rightmost: `if( j==(array.length-1)] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first element, use `if (j == 0)`.

For the last element, use `if (j == array[i].length-1)`.

**But please note the following:**

In order to compare elements in an array of a primitive type (`char`, `int`, `boolean`, etc):

```
if (array[i] == array[j])
```

In order to compare elements in an array of an Object type (`Character`, `Integer`, `Boolean`, etc):

```
if (array[i].equals(array[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The left most element would be `array[0][_]`

The right most is `array[array.length - 1][_]`

Top / bottom would be `array[_][array[0].length - 1]` or `array[_][0]`

Whichever is top/bottom left/right depends on your array naming conventions. array[x][y] or array[y][x], and such.

You don't need `if` to get those elements.
"_" used as placeholder here.